# How to set a region to "hover" state programmatically in jVectorMap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

How can I set Taiwan region to "hover" mode (colors + opacity + cursor...) when I actually hover China region, using Javascript/JQuery ?
Something like :

```
onRegionOver: function(event, code) {
    if ('CN' === code) {
        var obj = $('#world-map .jvectormap-container').data('mapObject');
        obj.setHovered('TW');
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setHovered()` works for individual regions like this:

```
mapObj.regions["TW"].element.setHovered(true);
```

Please note: depending from Your needs, you will end up to manage the region state by yourself, for example by using in `onRegionOut` trigger: `mapObj.regions["TW"].element.setHovered(false);`